# Adding a eventListener to elements with Class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have this challenge and i cant figure out how can i implement a function to get the click event on the squares. I want to get the click event on every button with square class.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-area',
  template: `
    <div id="statusArea" className="status">Next player: <span>X</span></div>
    <div id="winnerArea" className="winner">Winner: <span>None</span></div>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    <section>
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of [1, 2, 3]">
        <button *ngFor="let col of [1, 2, 3]" class="square" style="width:40px;height:40px;"></button>
      </div>
    </section>
  `,
  styles: []
})

export class MainAppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() { 
    const btn = document.getElementById('reset')
    const squares = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.square'))

    squares.forEach(square =>{
      square.addEventListener('click', function handleClicks(event){
        console.log('botão clicado');
      })
    })

    btn.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(event){
      console.log("clicado");
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: you're using `class` and `className` interchangably in your html strings!

Comment: Can't you just bind directly to the (click) event in the template?

Comment: @guzmanoj i cant

Comment: @JSilv even if i change to class or className, it doesnt give me the results that i expected

Comment: `<button *ngFor="let col of [1, 2, 3]" class="square" style="width:40px;height:40px;" (click)="onSquareClick()"></button>`

Comment: If you are sure you want to use document.querySelector() you may use this is ngAfterViewInit() hook.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure that this is clear: You shouldn't be poking around with the DOM in Angular.

The framework already provides mechanisms for Adding Events, Properties Binding and HTML selection (among dozens of more things)

In your case, you were trying to add the click event manually, but the framework  got you covered by simply adding the `(click)="onSquareClick()"` to your button element in the template.

```
<button *ngFor="let col of [1, 2, 3]" class="square" style="width:40px;height:40px;" (click)="onSquareClick()"></button>
```

If you really need to play with the DOM, Angular introduces the concept of Directives together with a few utilities that can be handy in such scenarios.
[Here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1336/how-to-do-dom-manipulation-properly-in-angular) you can find some examples